# Impossible to play my video on Safari browser

Tags: html, css

I looking for a way to play my video on Safari but I don't understand my video doesn't start ?
However, my video works on google chrome or edge.

[image]

Here is an idea of my code HTML

```
<video width="640" height="360" controls="true" autoplay loop muted playsinline>
  <source src="/Perso/WebSite.nsf/vLUpage/VIDEOS/$File/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Perhaps that, I have to use of the CSS ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingVideoforSafarioniPhone/CreatingVideoforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006514-SW6

Comment: Maybe your codec is not supported?

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling **cross-site tracking prevention** on you IOS device under **Safari** > **Preferences** > **Privacy**.

read this https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/safari/sfri40732/mac

Answer (score -2):

You can't play automatically a video on safari. The user has to engage an event and in this event you can play your video.

Comment: Untrue. If the video is muted with playsinline attribute added, it should autoplay without any issue: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/delivering_video_content_for_safari#3030251

Comment: Yes, I know that Apple says it is possible. But after developing several app, i saw that is not true. You have to be so lucky if you want your video to play in muted sound + playsinline attributs..